# Как переместить окно, если курсор выходит за его пределы на winapi?

Tags: c, winapi

Я делаю приложение на Си с нестандартным интерфейсом, перемещение окна выполняется с помощью SetWindowPos(). Если двигать курсор, нажав ЛКМ на заголовке, то окно движется только при относительно медленном перемещении мыши. Если быстро двинуть мышь вверх, курсор вылетает за пределы окна, и, видимо, WM_MOUSEMOVE перестает передавать координаты, как следствие, окно остаётся на месте.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте установить Capture. Тогда все мышиные события будут приходить к вашему окну, где бы не была мышь.

Comment: [`SetCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Я поставил SetCapture в WinMain, больше ничего в коде не менял.  Теперь при наведении курсора на моё окно курсор превращается в кружок, показывающий, что надо ждать (не знаю, как называется, раньше это были песочные часы). Окно движется как раньше, с проблемами.

Comment: Мне кажется, в WinMain может быть слишком рано. Например, окно не создано или что-то наподобие. Покажите лучше ваш код.

Comment: Я нашёл пример кода на оф сайте MS, сделал примерно также, кружок пропал, проблема осталась. SetCapture сделал после 'case WM_MOUSEMOVE:'

Comment: Перед 'break' поставил ReleaseCapture. Вот между двумя этими функциями и происходит получение координат курсора через GET_X_LPARAM и GET_Y_LPARAM, а затем перерисовка окна в новом месте. Простите, не знаю, как в комментарий код вставить.

Comment: А вы вставьте в вопрос, там есть наверху ссылка «править».

Comment: Перемещать мышью окно через `SetWindowPos` вообще не надо. Перемещением окна занимается сама ОС, реагируя на hittest код `HTCAPTION` в нужной позиции вашего окна, или всего окна (у @zorax в ответе последний фрагмент кода как раз это делает), а хуки - это уже перебор.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет решения с `SetCapture` сомневаюсь, у меня оно не работало как бы я не старался. Но у меня хорошо получилось с использованием хука на мышь.

Когда приходит сообщение `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` (нажатие левой кнопки мыши) в `WindowProc`, проверяем, находится ли позиция мыши в той области, где у нас осуществляется перемещение окна. Если да, то устанавливаем хук на событие `WH_MOUSE_LL`(функция, которая будет отлавливать сообщения не обязательно должна находиться в `DLL`) и запоминаем текущие координаты мыши. Функция, которую мы установили на хук, будет отвечать за перемещение окна.

Когда в этой функции приходит сообщение `WM_MOUSEMOVE`(перемещение мыши), перемещаем окно таким образом, чтобы координаты мыши оставались на том же месте в окне, как и были, когда была нажата левая кнопка мыши.

Если в этой функции приходит сообщение `WM_LBUTTONUP`(отпускание левой кнопки мыши), то убираем хук при помощи `UnhookWindowsHookEx(currentHook);`. Автоматически с этим выключается режим перемещения окна.

**Вот код:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

int width = 100;
int height = 100;

int mouseX = 0;
int mouseY = 0;

HHOOK currentHook;
HWND moveHwnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK mouseMove(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) 
{
    if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(currentHook);
    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT mshs = *(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        MoveWindow(moveHwnd, mshs.pt.x - mouseX, 
                   mshs.pt.y - mouseY, width, height, false);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(currentHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
        // Close window by pressing of Esc
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) {
                exit(0);
            }
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            int x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
            int y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam); 
            mouseX = x;
            mouseY = y;
            moveHwnd = hwnd;
            currentHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseMove, NULL, 0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcl = {0};
    wcl.cbSize          = sizeof(wcl);
    wcl.lpfnWndProc     = WindowProc;
    wcl.hInstance       = hInstance;
    wcl.hIcon           = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcl.hCursor         = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wcl.lpszClassName   = "OwnMoveTest";

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcl))
        return 0;

    HWND mainHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, wcl.lpszClassName,
                            "Caption", WS_POPUP, 200, 200, height,
                            width, 0, 0, wcl.hInstance, 0);

    ShowWindow(mainHwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(mainHwnd);

    // Paint window by white color
    PatBlt(GetDC(mainHwnd), 0, 0, width, height, WHITENESS);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    MSG msg;
    bool bRet;

    while((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, mainHwnd, 0, 0)) != 0) { 
        if (bRet != -1) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); 
            DispatchMessage(&msg); 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Вот результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Конечно, есть дефолтный вариант - обрабатывать сообщение `WM_NCHITTEST`. Программа работает точно так же, только пошустрее. Вот так будет выглядеть `WindowProc` в этом варианте:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
        // Close window by pressing of Esc
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) {
                exit(0);
            }
            break;

        case WM_NCHITTEST:
            return HTCAPTION;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то нажатой клавиши должно быть достаточно, чтобы всё само работало...

Comment: @Qwertiy , вообще-то нет. Когда мышь выходит за пределы окна, то сообщения о ней не передаются дальше. Вы вопрос вообще читали? Я запускал без этих сложностей, не работало.

Comment: Читал.. Это и странно, потому что по идее должно работать...

Comment: @Qwertiy а мой комментарий вы читали? Определение событий мыши таково, что они посылаются окну только когда мышь находится над поверхностью окна. За пределами окна сообщения не посылаются.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку @zorax сделал акцент на хуках, то я вынесу все же стандартный вариант решения подобной задачи с небольшим пояснением.

Дело тут в том, что ОСь не перемещает окно на каждое движение мыши, т.к. это дело затратное. То же самое касается изменения размеров окна мышью. Поэтому для перемещения окна с помощью мыши крайне нежелательно использовать [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) в ответ на [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx).

Для перемещения окна в Windows есть достаточно удобный функционал - [WM_NCHITTEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx), который позволяет избегать проблем с производительностью.

Например, для перемещения окна за его клиентскую часть, это сообщение можно обработать так:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT ht;

    switch (msg) {
        ...
        case WM_NCHITTEST:
            ht = DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            return (ht == HTCLIENT)? HTCAPTION : ht;
        ...
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

и этот код не перекроет встроенную обработку процедуры изменения размеров окна, при наличии соответствующего стиля.