# Как с помощью SetCapture() получить координаты курсора?

Tags: c, winapi

Как на Си получить координаты курсора через winapi, если он за пределами экрана? Мне посоветовали использовать SetCapture(), но я не понял, почитав описание, как она работает. [Как переместить окно, если курсор выходит за его пределы на winapi?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541216/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-winapi)

Координаты мне нужны для перемещения окна с нестандартным интерфейсом. Я добавил в код SetCapture, но это ничего не дало.
Код сейчас такой:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
  SetCapture ( hwnd );
  WmMouseMoveX = GET_X_LPARAM ( lParam );
  WmMouseMoveY = GET_Y_LPARAM ( lParam );

  // здесь код, перемещающий окно с помощь SetWindowPos()
  ...

  ReleaseCapture ( );
  break;
```

Comment: Как я понял, вы передвигаете окно. SetCapture() нужно делать в момент нажатия кнопки мыши, ReleaseCapture() -- в момент отпускания кнопки. Между этими событиями вы будете ловить WM_MOUSEMOVE, даже если мышь за пределами вашего окна.

Comment: @nzeemin я попробовал так сделать, разницы нет. SetCapture после case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:, а ReleaseCapture после case WM_LBUTTONUP:

Comment: Мне кажется, вам просто нужно внимательно прочитать описание SetCapture() и ReleaseCapture(). Их работа довольно проста, но судя по вашему коду, вы их просто неправильно используете.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте GetCursorPos: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx В описаниии функции есть советы по применению в случае нескольких десктопов.